# How can I add more types easily in the future

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns, architecture

Imagine I have this data structure:

```
const elements = [
    { type: 'text', value: '' },
    { type: 'text', multiple: true, value: ['', ''] },
    { type: 'select', value: '' },
    { type: 'select', multiple: true, value: ['', ''] },
    { type: 'date-range', value: { from: '', to: '' } },
    { type: 'date-range', multiple: true, value: { from: '', to: '' } },
    { type: 'area', value: { lat: '', long: '', rad: '' } },
];
```

Now, I created a Form using React/Typescript and Formik in order to submit this data to an API endpoint. But I feel that my solution is not scalable and I also had the type some props with `any`.

As you can see, I need to check for the type of the element but also if it's multiple or not. Making my code a bit hard to follow.

You can see my WIP solution in [this codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mopsa-vgkm2c?file=/src/App.tsx)

The core component is this one:

```js
const Field = ({
  element,
  onChange
}: {
  element: Element;
  onChange: (value: any) => void;
}) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      {element.type === "text" && (
        <Text
          value={element.value as any}
          isMultiple={element.multiple}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
      {/* Here I will add more types */}
      {element.type !== "text" && (
        <div key={element.id}>{JSON.stringify(element, null, 4)}</div>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is a way to have multiple components depending on their type, and how to handle the onChange methods without using 'any' (if that's possible). And a way to add more component types in the future.

Thanks a lot

My WIP solution => https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mopsa-vgkm2c?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: I think you should just make everything an array instead of trying to determine when it is and when it is not with a flag...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can handle this. I would look at making a [reducer with a dispatch event](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer) for each type of input that you have. Then you can fire the reducer and it can be ready to handle your data.

Another option is to use [narrowing](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-typescript/modules/learn-typescript-type-narrowing/cheatsheet). So you could provide a `__typename` to each of your elements that will distinguish them. Then switch based on this will provide a way to narrow down your types and what values to expect from them. You will need to build a typescript type for each `element` that you plan to use and then that info can be used with your handler so it can expect `elementA | elementB` as the type and based on the `__typename` you can